# ScaleMode doesn't work at all

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I might be doing something wrong, but I cannot make this work.

```
    var spriteView: SKView = self.view as SKView
    let scene = BattleScene(size: self.view.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill 
    spriteView.presentScene(scene)
```

No matter what option I select (ResizeFill, AspectFill, AspectFit etc), my scene view doesn't change at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SKScene.scaleMode`  are modes that determine how the scene’s area is mapped to the view that presents it.

You have set the size of your `SKScene` to be exactly the size of the `SKView` that presents it. The scaling mode property will not have any effect when the sizes are the same. Scaling mode is use to determine how to scale the scene when size of the presented scene does not match the size of the `SKView`.

For more information about each mode read.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/enum/SKSceneScaleMode